# User and game database many-to-many connection

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm trying to create a game database. I have already created a user table where the users, password and email are stored.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` char(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=111 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have also created a games table where the game type, name of the game, duration, description, active and who has created the game.

```
CREATE TABLE `games` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
      `name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
      `duration` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Completed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `createdBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The users will be able to create a game and invite x number of users, hence it will be a many-to-many relations. I have tried to create a table called active_games but I'm not sure how I should proceed. I need a connection so that I know who has created the game and who is playing that game.

```
CREATE TABLE `active_games` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `game_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`game_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What would be the next step? If a user creates a game and sends the "invite" to other friends, is it possible to automatically assign a game ID and the users invited to the that game ID? And if I want to find all the active games for a specific user, how can I do that?

Comment: To create an entry automatically you could add a trigger to the `games` table.

Answer (score 1):

You need two more tables.  `UserGames` would have information about users who create games:

```
CREATE TABLE UserGames (
    UserGameId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    userid int NOT NULL references users(id),
    gameid int not null references games(id),
    CreationDate datetime,
    . . .
);
```

And `GameInvites`:

```
CREATE TABLE GameInvites (
    GameInviteId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    UserGamesId int not null references UserGames(UserGamesId),
    invited_userid int NOT NULL references users(id),
    AcceptedFlag bit
    . . .
);
```

The `. . .` represent additional information that might want to store about each relationship.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit confused how to make the queries. If a user want to create a game and invite users, what would the query be?   And do I need the active_games table?

Comment: You need `active_games` if you want to see who is playing what game. You need `UserGames` if more than one user can create a game (although CreationDate is an attribute of the game so should be in the `Games` table). If it is one creator to game, that info can stay in the `Games` table.

As to how to make the queries, that all depends on what you want to know.

Comment: Thanks for the replay! Well I'm not sure how to set up the databases. If I use all the codes above will it work or do I have to modify/make some relations? And after I the setup of the database, how can I create a game (I have some users in the user table) and "send" the invitation to the user. Which table should I use when the game needs some "status" updates or when it is completed? I'm not so familiar with relation-databases and how to keep track of the different tables. Hope you can explain it to me :)